# Socketed or Soldered BIOS?

Tags: soldering

My BIOS died (*ASUS M2N SLI* Deluxe motherboard) on me and I would like to remove it from its place. But I cannot figure out whether it is socketed or soldered. Here is a picture of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjzPm.jpg

(I will not try to desolder, don't have the skills. Hope it is socketed. )

Comment: How do (did) you kill just the BIOS chip?

Comment: @Martin: **ASUS update utility**. that darn app started looping over and after waiting 10 mins i pretty much knew that the BIOS was corrupted. After reboot black screen, no post, no nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is soldered direct on to the PCB. The package is a [PLCC with J lead pins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_leaded_chip_carrier). It is best removed with a hot air desoldering station with the right nozzle to go around the chip and a sucker to hold it when removed. But it could possibly be desoldered with braid and enough heat from an iron, with a high risk of lifting pads and tracks from the board, depending on your experience. In your case, I think you need to look at a new motherboard.

Answer (score 2):

Don't throw it out yet!

This motherboard has the [CrashFree BIOS 3](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM2/M2NSLI_Deluxe/) feature which allows for reflash from a USB drive even if the main BIOS is corrupted.

Comment: yes it does but it is inaccessible, since it is on the same chip. there is no output to my screen, nothing shows up, even when i insert usb or floppy.

Comment: As long as the flash chip isn't dead, reflashing with CrashFree 3 should work properly. Here are some more links with details on how others got it to work: [link 1](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1111827%22) [link 2](http://www.hardwareanalysis.com/content/topic/70427/)

Comment: i finally got my hands on a PCI graphics card. i tried the steps given on the links, but nothing :( i guess the chip is fubar.